# How to set custom buttons (text) in jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog

I do get that we easily can set the `Close` button text to a variable, using `closeText` option

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeText: btnCancel, // <-----
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

but how about a **custom name**?

this does not work :(

```
var btnResetMapping = 'Reset Mapping';

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeText: btnCancel,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        btnResetMapping: function() {  // <-----
            // logic here
        },
    }
});
```

This can be seen as weird question, but my variable, in the code is:

```
var btnResetMapping = '<%= Resources.PARbuttons.btnResetMapping %>';
```

witch is loaded correctly from the Global Resources file, with the correct sentence for the applied localization.

it works fine using:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeText: btnCancel,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        '<%= Resources.PARbuttons.btnResetMapping %>': function() {  // <-----
            // logic here
        },
    }
});
```

But I'm refactoring this as place the javascript file in it's own place (alone file), and I want to, not only do this way (separate HTML from Javascript - It's a Business Web Aplication that is always loaded from the INTRANET, never using Internet btw) but to understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Fine. You try putting the string inside btnResetMapping directly into the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bracket notation, like this:

```
var myButtons = { Close: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }  };
myButtons[btnResetMapping] = function() { ...logic here... };
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeText: btnCancel,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    buttons: myButtons
});
```

Just make sure `btnResetMapping` is defined *before* this code runs and you're all set :)